# ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row while using update

Tags: oracle, sql-update

Hi I have the following update query:

```
UPDATE buchung b 
SET kst_id = (SELECT kst_id 
              FROM kostenstelle 
              WHERE b.Kostenstelle = kostenstelle)
```

I get the Error in the Topic and I know why.

My Question: Is it possible to update just the rows which are unique?

Comment: I don't have an Oracle box at hand to test whether the syntax is valid but can't you replace the `=` operator with `IN()`?

Comment: What makes the rows unique?  Apparently it isn't `b.Kostenstelle` or `kostenstelle`.

Comment: the porblem is that the kst_id is unique but the kostenstelle ist not. it can happen that there are two kostenstelle with different kst_id. So i just want to update where kostenstelle is unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to do this.

- Add a `WHERE` clause that checks that for the specific `b.kostenstelle` value there is exactly one row  in table `kostenstelle`:

  ```
  update buchung b 
  set kst_id = (select kst_id 
                from kostenstelle 
                where b.Kostenstelle = kostenstelle)
  where 1 = (select count(*) 
             from kostenstelle 
             where b.Kostenstelle = kostenstelle) ;
  ```
- exactly as before, only using a different way to check for only one. It may be more efficient, with an index on `kostenstelle (kostenstelle, kst_id)`:

  ```
  update buchung b 
  set kst_id = (select kst_id 
                from kostenstelle 
                where b.Kostenstelle = kostenstelle)
  where not exists 
        ( select 0
          from kostenstelle 
          where b.Kostenstelle = kostenstelle
          having min(kst_id) < max(kst_id)      -- the PK of kostenstelle
        ) ;
  ```
- use the `COUNT()` window function to determine the count:

  ```
  with upd as
  ( select b.kst_id, 
           k.kst_id as k_kst_id
           count(distinct k.kst_id) over (partition by k.kostenstelle) as cnt
    from  buchung b 
      join kostenstelle 
        on b.Kostenstelle = k.kostenstelle
  )
  update upd
  set kst_id = k_kst_id 
  where cnt = 1 ;
  ```
- and a variation on the last one, where it may be more obvious what the code is doing:

  ```
  with unq as
  ( select kostenstelle, 
           min(kst_id) as kst_id
    from kostenstelle 
    group by kostenstelle
    having min(kst_id) = max(kst_id)
  ) ,
  upd as
  ( select b.kst_id, 
           k.kst_id as k_kst_id
    from  buchung b 
      join unq k 
        on b.Kostenstelle = k.kostenstelle
  )
  update upd
  set kst_id = k_kst_id ;
  ```